Looking for UK Sci-Fi TV Movie about sentient alien plants
This is vague, but this was shown possibly late 80's early 90's on UK TV and certainly a British production.
The movie (tv movie or possibly a 2,3-part series?) starts with the filming of a gardening programme, the TV crew are set up as well as the presenters to make a live broadcast. During the live broadcast one of the presenters unearths a body.  The transmission is stopped and the police called in where many more bodies are found in the garden - all in perfect condition.
During the course of the movie it turns out that these bodies are actually sentient alien plants.
One of the humans ends up having a relationship with someone who turns out to be one of the aliens in human form and whose job it was to protect these other 'plants' and eventually find a way to leave earth.
At the end of the programme, the human who had the relationship finds the alien dead in the form of a dead plant in human shape...
Any ideas?

Not vague at all, you've actually provided plenty of details, thanks. :)

Sounds like the TV movie The Plant that aired on the BBC in 1995. From Wiki:

In a garden in a London suburb, corpses sprout out of the earth on during a live television gardening programme called Down to Earth. However, it soon appears that these human bodies are not dead people, they are grown there, like plants.

It turns out an alien grows them there. The movie is available in 6 parts on Youtube. Here's part 1. 
